# Restricting access to ASMX web service

Tags: php, web-services, soap, asmx

There id this existing ASP.NET (2.0) web service that's called from PHP. Runs fine.  Now the need arises to restrict access. Constraint: I currently don't have access to IIS/Windows account management to implement something robust,.

I'm thinking about adding a SOAP header to the PHP call, containing a secret key, and then checking the contents of the header in the ASP.NET web service.

I'm fairly new to SOAP, so I might be way off though, any better ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

SOAP Headers would work. So would a client certificate. The question will be: what can PHP handle?

Comment: thanks,that's a good question (I think PHP can handle both). I was just curious whether there was a glaring oversight on my behalf.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the book [Mastering Web services security By Bret Hartman, Donald J. Flinn, Konstantin Beznosov, Shirley Kawamoto](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=m2Ro_XIz3c4C&pg=RA1-PA64&lpg=RA1-PA64&dq=Restricting+access+to+ASP.NET+web+service&source=bl&ots=z76_4eJOrF&sig=TtU_amfcoGT1o19KmjZjrWNBxQQ&hl=en&ei=MsOLSsngEdyXkAWc9KAt&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1#v=onepage&q=&f=false)

> SUMMARY:Authorization policies
>   restrict access to many different
>   collections of ... of Web Services
>   security. For this scenario, we've
>   chosen to use ASP.NET.

Comment: Aren't policies part of WS-Security?